# Combining test-Path -Path with a regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

In Jenkins I'm creating a PowerShell script. This is working:

```
if (Test-Path -Path "$baseDirectory\s*") {...}
```

But this is "dangerous" and not "safe" enough.

The directory name will be: sdd or sddd (d=digits). 
So the name starts with the character "s" and is 2 and later three digits long.

I have tried the following:

```
if (Test-Path -Path "$baseDirectory\ -match 's(\d{2,3})'") {...}
```

and

```
if (Test-Path -Path "-match '$baseDirectory\s(\d{2,3})'") {...}
```

and all kind of little differences.

If I do this with s* than the script returns directory name s54, s55 etc.

I'm expecthing, if possible, the same result with the regular expression instead of "no directory found".

Comment: the `-Path` parameter of `Test-Path` DOES NOT accept anything other than wildcards - no regex at all. from ReadingTheFriendlyManual >>> `-Path <String[]> - Specifies a path to be tested. Wildcard characters are permitted. If the path includes spaces, enclose it in quotation marks.`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to see if one or more folders can be found with that name.

```
if ([bool](Get-ChildItem "$baseDirectory\s*" -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 's\d{2,3}$' })) {
    # your code goes here
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Try use the follow regex:

```
s\d{2,3}
```

[For Example, Click Here](https://regex101.com/r/lqMgR6/1)

Good Luck!

Comment: That is working were I'm searching for but in combination with powershell 

    if (Test-Path -Path "$baseDirectory\s\d{2,3}") {...}  

it returns "nothing found"